# Jquery if checkbox is checked Bootstrap switch

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I use Bootstrap switch plugin to make my checkboxes looks like switch buttons. I need to check if the checkbox is checked in jQuery. I Googled a lot and I tried some advice and code snippets but without success.

I think the cleanest code I found is

```
$('#checkbox').attr('checked');
```

but it still wont work on my website. I have declared jQuery in head. I try to use this snippets on non-bootstrap-switch-checkboxes but still no success.

**JS:**

```
 <script>
    $(function(){
      $(".odeslat").click(function(){
           $('#pozadavky').slideUp(100);
           $('#datumpick').slideDown(300);

       var typpaliva = 'nic';
       var malpg = 'nic';¨

       /***Important condition***/

       if ($('#uho').attr('checked')) {
            $.cookie("typpaliva", "Diesel");
       }
       else {
            $.cookie("typpaliva", "Benzin");
       }


 /**********************************************/


    $.ajax({
   url: 'http://podivej.se/script_cas.php',
   data: {druh: '30'},
   type: "POST",
   success: function(data){
            alert($.cookie('typpaliva')); 
            alert($.cookie('malpg'));   
   }
   });

  });
});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="testcheckbox" id="uho"/>
```

Comment: *"it still wont work on my website"* Please be more precise. What *exactly* does not work? What happens? What do you expect to happen? What have you done to debug the problem?

Comment: How do you trigger the switch ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use :

```
if ($('#uho').is(':checked')) {
```

instead of

```
if ($('#uho').attr('checked')) {
```

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar How do you tell when the user checks or unchecks?

Comment: @pathros, you can register a `.click(function()..` or `.change(function()..` event handlers and then check `$(this).is(':checked')` which return true if checked and false if unchecked.

Answer (score 11):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MDu66/)**

Use **[`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)** instead of `.attr()`.

- `.prop` returns - 'true' or 'false'. **Use this**
- [`.is(':checked')`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) returns - 'true' or 'false' -`:checked` is a pseudo slector. **Or this**
- `.attr` returns - 'checked' or 'attribute undefined'.

---

```
$('#uho').prop('checked')

if($('#uho').prop('checked')){
    $.cookie("typpaliva", "Diesel");
}
else {
    $.cookie("typpaliva", "Benzin");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on a comment in the accepted answer, here's how I solved this for a Terms and Conditions checkbox in bootstrap:

HTML

```
<div class="checkbox">
   <label>
      <input id="agreeTAC" type="checkbox" value="">
      I have read and agree to the TERMS AND CONDITIONS listed on this page.
   </label>
</div>
```

Javascript (with jQuery)

```
$("#agreeTAC").change(function(){
    var agreed = $(this).is(':checked');
    console.log("agreeTAC value changed and is ", agreed);
    if(agreed === true) { 
       // do 'true' stuff, like enabling a 'Continue' button
    }
    else {
       // do 'false' stuff, like disabling a 'Continue' button
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('#uho').attr('checked')` will return undefined. you can use `$('#uho:checkbox:checked').length` property to check if checkbox is checked or not. Try this snippet:

```
 if ($('#uho:checkbox:checked').length > 0) {
        $.cookie("typpaliva", "Diesel");
   }
   else {
        $.cookie("typpaliva", "Benzin");
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

- use this code on page load

  document.getElementById("#uho").checked = true;

Comment: Please tell Why is that necessary while `OP` has `jQuery` ?

Comment: This is direct method. you can use java script for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
  if($('#chkBoxID').is(":checked")){ // do stuff }
```